# Question about repeating the object after だ

Tags: translation, expressions, manga

I am a total noob when it comes to Japanese, so I am reading　よつば　Vol.1 to try and pick up some simple words/phrases.

On page 4, Yotsuba's father says, in response to her asking if there is a festival that day:

> 学校だ学校

I understand that he is telling her that there is a school, but is there a reason why he says this instead of just

> 学校だ

I figure this may just be an expressive thing, almost as if to say "Calm down, it's just a school", but I wanted to check if there is some grammatical reason why he says this.

Apologies if this question does not belong here, or if I have misunderstood something!

The panel in question:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 「Noun + だ/よ/だよ, etc. + Same Noun」

is simply an emphatic way of saying

> 「Noun + だ/よ/だよ, etc.」

This expression is very common in informal daily conversations.  You may want to remember that in Japanese, words tend to get repeated more often than in English.

Thus, 「学校{がっこう}だ学校」 here means "***You have school today.  School!***"

「学校」 here means "school" and not "**a** school".

Comment: Thank you for your answer, although I am not convinced that it means "you have school today", because I'm pretty sure she doesn't have school that day - I guess this depends on the context

Comment: @Bassie he says it in response to her asking about "today" (きょう), and later on he says summer vacation starts tomorrow. So, "you have school today" does seem like a reasonable inference to make (not that the sentence literally means that, but that it's what he's trying to convey). Though, possibly a special event for the end of the school year, rather than actual class.

Comment: @EthanKaminski OK thanks for clearing that up, I guess that does make sense if you only look at that panel

Comment: This girl is 5 years old, just came to Japan, and [doesn't even understand what a school is](http://dengekionline.com/comic-trial/1510/yotsubato01/?page=3). So the father is just saying "It's (something called) a school."